# Extending a function from $C^1[0,1/2]$ to $C^1[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Suppose $f\in C^1[0,1/2]$, the space of continuously differentiable functions on $[0,1/2]$. Does there exists $g\in C^1[0,1]$ such that $g\mid_{[0,1/2]}=f$?

In other words can a function in $C^1[0,1/2]$ be extended to a function in $C^1[0,1]$?

**My attempt:** I thought of letting $g(x)=f(1/2)$ for all $x\in [1/2,1]$. However, I later realized that this only guarantees the continuity of $g$ and not the differentiability at $1/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $g(x)=f(x)$ for $0 \leq x \leq \frac1  2$ and $g(x)=f'(\frac 1 2 ) (x-\frac 1 2 )+f(\frac 1 2)$ for $\frac 1 2  \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: That's nicer because it generalizes to higher order derivatives (with $g$ as the Taylor polynomial of $f$ at $x=1/2$).

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the function by “mirroring” the graph at $(1/2, f(1/2))$, i.e.
$$
 g(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x) & 0 \le x \le 1 \\
2 f(\frac 12) - f(1-x)  & 1/2 < x \le 1 \, .
\end{cases}
$$